# React Native TabNavigator is hiding when ScrollView is long

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I'm using TabNavigator from this library https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab
and on screen I have ScrollView it is really long and my Tabs are hiding, what to do in order to not hide tabs?

here is the code:

```
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Home',
            headerLeft: null
        }
    },
    Notes: {
        screen: Notes,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Notes',
            headerLeft: null
        }
    },
    Tasks: {
        screen: Tasks,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Tasks',
            headerLeft: null
        }
    },
    Events: {
        screen: Events,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Events',
            headerLeft: null
        }
    }
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'green'
    },
});


const plannings = StackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    Register: {
        screen: Register,
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null
        }
    },
    Home: {
        screen: TabNav
    }
}, {
    headerMode: 'screen'
});
```

Comment: tried to make position absolute for content but it's not scrollable

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the result, it sounds to me that you re embedding the tabNavigator inside the scrollView. The other way around should be the case

Comment: can you show us the structure of your code here ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found this solution and it works for me:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
     <View style={{height: 400, width: 400}}>                 
       <ScrollView>
         <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
            // Your data here
         </View> 
      </ScrollView>
      <TextInput style={{backgroundColor: '#c4c4c4dd', position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0}} />
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: Where's this code from? How do we know where the issue was how it got fixed?